# How to change whole views in MVVM without “grandparent” DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, navigation

All examples which I’ve seen on the Internet has two areas – one area is for buttons to change views and another area is for views which should be changed by that buttons. So it works until you try to access commands located in the "grand-parent" data-context. However, I would like to change an entire view to another view without dividing areas or any side bar and sending data from View1 to View2, then updating View1.

I am trying to change Views in an MVVM application.  For example, I have “ApplicationView” ( a host which contains DataTemplates of Views1(UserControl1) and View2(UserControl2)). These user controls have its own datacontext.
xaml Of ApplicationView is:

```
<Window ……..>    
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localViewModel:VMMain}">
        <localView:MainView/>            
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localViewModel:VMEditStudent}">
        <localView:EditStudentView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>    
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

View 1(UserControl1) has own DataContext:
[image]

And View 2(UserControl2) has own DataContext too:

[image]

What I want is select an item(Adam ) in the DataGrid, click a button “Edit”, then View1 should be replaced by View 2 with filled data from a datagrid.  As I understand I should change View1 by handling command of button “Edit”, and then View 2 should be displayed, then I change data and then View1 should be updated. How to do it?

Some examples with code will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you had a look at Prism Framework and it's RegionManager?

Comment: @Tseng, Yeah, I've seen this examples and these examples was wit sidebar.

Comment: RegionManager works independently of the Sidebar. You define regions in XAML and name them, then navigate within them from code. The reference app shows best practices and such behavior as you suggest isn't considered best practice on Desktop and resembles more to Mobile Apps usability. Still the RegionManager should also cover your case

Comment: @Tseng, thanks. However, I couldn't find a good example without sidebar navigation. Please, could you be kind to share some example or link to see the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is similar to the typical example that you mentioned except that your view button is in one of the views. The solution is simply to data bind the `Button.Command` property to the command in the parent view model. That can be accomplished with a simple `RelativeSource Binding`:

In `UserControl1` XAML:

```
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourParentView}}}" />
```

In parent view model Edit Command, you'd need something like this:

```
CurrentPageViewModel = new ViewModelForUserControl2(UserControl1.SelectedDataObject);
```

Of course, you'd also have to expose the selected item as a `DependencyProperty` from `UserControl1` so that you could pass it to `UserControl2`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that View1 should contain Data template for View2? But my view1 cannot contain ContentControl for changing Views as View1 has Datagrid. Should CurrentPageViewModel property be static in ApplicationViewModel then the objects get created (CurrentView.ChangeViewCommand = this.ChangeViewCommand set  ViewViewModel2 from ViewViewmodel1? Thanks.

Comment: am I right? <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditStudentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type localView:ApplicationView}}}"

Comment: Do I understand correctly "In parent view model Edit Command, you'd need something like this: CurrentPageViewModel...", that CurrentPageViewModel must be in View1ViewModel? However I have a property "CurrentPageViewModel" just in ApplicationViewModel. I do not have CurrentPageViewModel property in View1ViewModel. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Do I understand correctly that View1 should contain Data template for View2?*... I don't remember saying anything like that. *Should CurrentPageViewModel property be static in ApplicationViewModel?*... no. *am I right?*... you forgot `DataTemplate.` from the `Binding Path`. *CurrentPageViewModel must be in View1ViewModel?*... no, it should be in the main (parent) view model... that's why we're using the `RelativeSource Binding` to reach it there.

Comment: sorry that I can understand by the first time. However, how can I set CurrentPageViewModel in ViewModelView1, if this property is initialised in ApplicationViewModel? "you forgot DataTemplate. from the Binding Path." - where should I have DataTemplate. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: *However, how can I set CurrentPageViewModel in ViewModelView1, if this property is initialised in ApplicationViewModel?*... you can't... you set it in the parent view model where the property is. The idea is that you are calling a command in that view model that sets the property in that same view model. `you forgot DataTemplate`... sorry, I meant that you forgot to use `DataContext.` in your `Binding Path`.

Comment: so DataContext should be ApplcationViewModel in my case for View1? Not ViewViewModel1?

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not here to teach you WPF. As such, this will be my LAST comment... take from it what you can. You have a Window with an object set as `DataContext`... this object should be your main view model and have your `CurrentPageViewModel` property and your `ICommand` *that changes that property value*. You use a `RelativeSource Binding` from any child control to access that `ICommand`. That's it! The `ICommand` is triggered from whichever view, it changes the parent view model property and the view is changed. That's all there is to it. END!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. But I forgot to ask about sending data from view1 to view2 and back. Is it possible? Thanks a lot:). Be kind with me, please:)